# double post entry into db while using function?

Tags: php, mysql, function, mysqli

hello i have a problem using a function to insert user data into a db. the query will be executed twice and i have no clue why this is happening.

i do use this code:

if (empty($_POST['submit']) === false && empty($errors) === true) {

```
$random = substr(str_shuffle('./0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'), 0, 22);;

$timezone = 'Europe/Berlin';
date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
$timestamp = time();
$time = date("d.m.Y - H:i:s", $timestamp);

$register_data = array(
    'a'     => $_POST['a'],
    'b'     => $_POST['b'],
    'c'     => $_POST['c'],
    'd'     => $_POST['d'],
    'e'     => $_POST['e'],
    'f'     => md5($_POST['password']),
    'g'     => md5($random),
    'h' => $time,
);
register_user($register_data);

if (register_user($register_data) === true) {
    echo "done";
}   
exit();
```

}

and the functions are:

```
function array_sanitize(&$item){
    global $db;
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $item);
}

function register_user($register_data){
    global $db;
    array_walk($register_data, 'array_sanitize');

    $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($register_data)) . '`';
    $data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $register_data) . '\'';

    $insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO `table1` ($fields) VALUES ($data) "); 
    return (true);
}
```

but when replacing this function:

```
function register_user($register_data){
    global $db;
    array_walk($register_data, 'array_sanitize');

    $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($register_data)) . '`';
    $data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $register_data) . '\'';

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `table1` ($fields) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,NOW())";
        if($query = $db->prepare($sql)){
            $query->bind_param('sssssss', $data);
            $query->execute();

            if ($query->affected_rows == 1) {
                echo 'success';
            } else {
                echo 'nope';
            }
        }

    return (true);
}
```

and removing the last key from the array $register_data does not work at all.

it would be great if someone could help me out.

thanks alot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You called this `register_user($register_data);` twice. Once directly and once part of an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know php but try sth like this:

```
$result=register_user($register_data);

if ($result == true) {    
 echo "done";
}
```